# Good text and reference in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

I have just started reading real analysis. The topics include sequences, series, continuity, differentiability, integration, series of functions , calculus in higher dimensions etc.

I am in need of a text and a reference book.

Can someone please tell me about it?

The text should not be very broad as I need something to finish before my exam.But the reference should be broad, with full of exercise and examples. Hint to exercise will help me a lot.

Waiting for your response.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbook-recommendation%5D+analysis

Comment: Advanced Calculus Book by Patrick Fitzpatrick is a good start.